# Struggling to call a Jscript function within jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jscript

I have a small MVC5/C# Web application. In short, users will select a location from a dropdown ("#UnitList").  This fires the jquery event, to populate the next dropdown ("#CheckItem") with a list of contacts associated to the location selected.

Being very inexperienced in Jscript and Jquery, I am lost.

Additionally, on the same event, I need to populate an element (hidden text box).

In order to fill the hidden elements, I use this code

```
$(function () {
  $("[name='UnitList']").change(function () {
    $("#DeliveryUnitID").val($(this).val());    
  });
});
```

To run the Jquery that populates the second dropdown:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#UnitList").change(function() {
    var batchId = $(this).val();
    var urlForModesl = getURLBase() + "ICS_Requisitions/Details";
    urlForModesl = urlForModesl + "/" + batchId;
    var modelsHtml = "";

    $('#CheckItem')
      .find('option')
      .remove()
      .end()
      .append('<option value="Select Contact"></option>')
      .val('Contact')

    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: urlForModesl,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(jsonData) {

        $.each(jsonData, function(key, value) {

          modelsHtml += "<option value='" + value.LoginID + "'>" + value.ContactName + "</option>";
        });

        $("#CheckItem").html(modelsHtml);
        $("#DeliveryUnitID").val($(this).val())
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
    });
  });
});
```

I am aware that I have two functions with the same name "$("#UnitList").change(function ()" and that this is very bad and causing conflicts. This is what I am trying to resolve.

I have tried to simply add the element update within the Jquery code, but that did not work.

I placed the following code

```
$("#DeliveryUnitID").val($(this).val())
```

Inside the Jquery, right after:

```
$("#CheckItem").html(modelsHtml);
```

But that does not work.  The hidden elements are still empty.

I tried creating a function called foo, with the element update, and call that function from at the end of the jquery.

```
foo();

<script>
function foo() {        
  $("#DeliveryUnitID").val($(this).val());
}
```

That also left the element #DeliveryUnitID empty.

I know that I can't have two functions with the same name, but that's the only way I can get it working where the query populates the drop down, and then the hidden element is populated too.  BUT . . . that's bad coding AND, for about 5% of the users, it fails.

I can't quite figure out how to make both happen with one onchange event.

Comment: I no longer respond to unindented code

Comment: "*two functions with the same name "$("#UnitList").change(function ()"*" - no, you have two separate event handlers.  The functions are unnamed, anonymous function callbacks.  This is not an issue by itself, only what they *do* that may conflict.

Comment: @freedomn-m:  So, it's okay to have two separate event handlers for same?  Would the problem me the order in which they fire?  Can I force one to first first?

Comment: @ExecChef not sure where that claim is coming from. Only 3 of your latest questions have been edited, and none of them have been changed to be left aligned. You've done that yourself. I checked to see if someone had intentionally done that in error. Regards your issue, the problem is because you're invoking `this` within the AJAX request callback function, so it will not refer to the element which raised the event. To fix the problem, move that line to the start of the `change` event handler.

Comment: To merge them as-is (with no functional changes), you would move `$("#DeliveryUnitID").val($(this).val());` to be the *first* line of `$("#UnitList").change(function () {`

Comment: As I said, it depends on what they *do*.  Eg you might have a click event that hides a panel and a separate event on the same element that submits a form.   Without HTML, I'm *guessing* you have `<select id=UnitList name=UnitList>` - it's unclear why one handler is against the ID and the other against the name, so they *could* be different elements.

Comment: If your code was indented, you'd see that adding after `$("#CheckItem").html(modelsHtml);` would be inside the ajax callback rather than directly in the event - whether that's desired or a problem (beyond the `this` issue as noted above) depends on your requirement.

Comment: As an aside, note that `$('#CheckItem').find('option').remove().end().append('<option value="Select Contact"></option>').val('Contact');` can be replaced with this: `$('#CheckItem').html('<option value="Select Contact"></option>');`

Comment: You may be mixing multiple event handlers with the DRY principle - which says to not repeat code - there's no repeated code if the events do different things / have different *responsibilities*.  Can be a problem with maintenance if you rename the element then only change one of the event handlers.

Comment: @freedomn-m:  Moving '$("#DeliveryUnitID").val($(this).val()); to be the first line of $("#UnitList").change(function () {'  worked.  The events are all firing now.  I will add that we have some users who remote in Virtual.  Others are in office using desktops.  I am puzzled as they behave very differently.

Comment: If your script is in a .js file, it could be that it's being cached somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used jQuery, so here's what I'm seeing:

**On `change` Event:**

1. Get the value of the #UnitList `<select>` (**potential bug:** these aren't being stored anywhere)
2. Clear the options
3. Re-populate with new ones from AJAX Request
4. Try to get value of new options (still within initial AJAX request, which might also be a bug? Like I said, it's been a while since I've used jQuery).

It looks like you might have a state-management issue?

**Potential fixes:**

1. Store values of first dropdown before you clear them.
2. Use the stored value to populate #DeliveryUnitID *after* the AJAX request
3. Use some `if` statements or remove the event listener to not constantly be running your code on `change` event once you get the data you need...unless you need it to be running constantly.

To me, it would seem beneficial (from a code pov and maybe also a UX perspective) to programmatically build a second dropdown to keep things clearer, but that might be overkill for what you're trying to accomplish.